# Is it haram to talk to Jin?

Tags: halal-haram, jinn

One of the things we know about the Jinn world is that there are the believers and there are the non-believers, we mainly encounter Jinn in our world in harmful situation such as VooDoo or possession!.

But what we normally don't hear about is Jins interacting with humans for non-harmful purposes, e.g. engaging in conversations and exchanging information!

So are Jinn forbidden to interact with us or could it be that there is some constraint in which they can't do so?

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, please see my answer below regardless of the votes.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning your interesting query that you asked:

> Is it haram to talk to Jin?

---

As the concise answer:

Firstly it is remarked that there are two sorts of Jinn:

1: Mo’men (or Muslim) Jinn

2: Kafir Jinn

---

Secondly: it is declared that (what can be inferred from Shia 14 infallibles’ narrations) :

> It can be investigated as a permissible practice if firstly the Jinn
>   who you are talking or having relation to, is from Mo’men Jinn, not
>   Kaffer. Likewise by observing some Islamic condition you can have
>   relation (or taling)…

---

As a related more info. : [www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/search/site/jinn)

---

**References:**

- [www.hawzah.net](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/63468/%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B7-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D9%81%D9%82%D9%87%DB%8C)
- [www.islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa606)

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. So let me answer this question with another question. Is it permissible to talk to humans whether Muslim or non Muslim. Answer: of course it is halal. Let me provide some evidences to show my point.

**Jinns have the faculty Hearing**

> His father who was under the care of Abu Sa'eed said: "Abu Sa'eed said to me: 'If you are in the desert, raise your voice when you say the Adhan, for I heard the Messenger of ALLAAH say: 'No jinn, human, tree or rock will hear it, but it will bear witness for you.'"

**Jinns have the faculty/senses to converse with human beings**

Hadith #1

> ALLAAH Messenger (ﷺ) ordered me to guard the Zakat revenue of Ramadan. Then somebody came to me and started stealing from the foodstuff. I caught him and said, "I will take you to ALLAAH Messenger (ﷺ)!" Then Abu Huraira described the whole narration and said: That person said (to me), "(Please don't take me to ALLAAH Messenger (ﷺ) **and I will tell you a few words** by which ALLAAH will benefit you.) When you go to your bed, recite Ayat-al-Kursi, (2.255) for then there will be a guard from ALLAAH who will protect you all night long, and Satan will not be able to come near you till dawn." (When the Prophet (ﷺ) heard the story) he said (to me), "He (who came to you at night) told you the truth although he is a liar; and it was Satan." (Bukhari in the chapter of virtues of the Quraan)

In this hadith the word shaytan was used and we know shaytan is an evil jinn. There is the shaytan we know of called iblees and then the other shaytan who are evil and have disbelieved.

> And [mention] when We said to the angels, "Prostrate to Adam," and they prostrated, except for Iblees. He was of the jinn and departed from [i.e., disobeyed] the command of his Lord. Then will you take him and his descendants as allies other than Me while they are enemies to you? Wretched it is for the wrongdoers as an exchange. (Quraan chapter 18 verse 50)

> From the evil of the retreating whisperer 
> Who whispers [evil] into the breasts of mankind 
> From among the jinn and mankind (Last three ayats(verses) of chapter 114 in the Quraan)

Hadith #2

> Some people asked ALLAAH Messenger (ﷺ) about the fore-tellers He said. ' They are nothing" They said, 'O ALLAAH Messenger (ﷺ)! Sometimes they tell us of a thing which turns out to be true." ALLAAH Messenger (ﷺ) said, "**A Jinn snatches that true word and pours it Into the ear of his friend** (the fore-teller) (as one puts something into a bottle) The foreteller then mixes with that word one hundred lies." (Bukhari in the chapter of medicine)

Hadith #3

> That once he was in the company of the Prophet (ﷺ) carrying a water pot for his ablution and for cleaning his private parts. While he was following him carrying it (i.e. the pot), the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Who is this?" He said, "I am Abu Huraira." The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Bring me stones in order to clean my private parts, and do not bring any bones or animal dung." Abu Huraira went on narrating: So I brought some stones, carrying them in the corner of my robe till I put them by his side and went away. When he finished, I walked with him and asked, "What about the bone and the animal dung?" He said, "They are of the food of Jinns. **The delegate of Jinns of (the city of) Nasibin came to me--and how nice those Jinns were--and asked me for the remains of the human food.** I invoked ALLAAH for them that they would never pass by a bone or animal dung but find food on them." (Bukhari in the chapter of Merits of the Helpers in Madinah)

Hadith #4

> Jabir [may ALLAAH be pleased with him] said: “The Messenger of ALLAAH came out to his Companions, and recited Surat Ar-Rahman from its beginning to its end for them, and they were silent. So he said: ‘I recited it to the Jinns on the ‘Night of the Jinns,’ and they had a better response to it than you did. Each time I came to ALLAAH saying: ‘Which of your Lords favor do you deny.’ They said: “We do not deny any of Your favors our Lord! And Yours is praise.” (Tirmidhi in the chapter of chapters on tafsir)

**Conclusion**

From the aforementioned ahadith we see that a good or evil jinn can be around you. It would be possible they might interact with you in a good way (dreams, coming in person, etc.) or bad way (evil dreams, waswasa, negative thoughts, etc.). However, they are there and who knows you might receive a sign the next time you try to say "hello jinn, i want to talk to you".

**Have a nice day!**

Answer (score -3):

It's haram (forbidden) to seek the help from the jinn, whether it's Muslim or not and for any kind of purpose (i.e.: good and bad).

About talking to the jinn, here is the reference: https://islamqa.info/en/7654

Comment: I hope it is not a jinn who downvote.

Comment: It would have been better to summarize or elaborate an own answer based on the linked fatwa than saying here is an answer this isn't plagiarism, but a very low quality answer!