# Seeing a Devil is possible?

Tags: shaitan

Can anyone see a devil? Is it possible? If someone saw a devil then what are the consequences? And what are the reasons that why that specific person saw a devil?

Comment: I would recommend reading this book "kitab Syhafi M3 Jinni Muslim" A book about a conversation between a Journalist and a Muslim Jinn! First I though it was made up but he seems to backup the majority of statements from the Quran and hadeeth!

Comment: unfortuantly I asked a similar question http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28628/is-it-haram-to-talk-to-jin but there are no detailed answers

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it depends on what do you mean by "seeing". Seeing his true form? Or any form?

According to this [fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83888), it is **possible** somehow. There are 3 mentioned cases:

1) The jinn may appear in the form of a *human being* as recorded in Sahih al-Bukhari when a **devil** came to Abu Hurairah (Radiya Allahu Anhu) in the shape of a poor man and Abu Hurairah found the **devil** taking much food of charity.

2) The jinn may appear in a form of *black dog* as [confirmed](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihmuslim/132-Sahih%20Muslim%20Book%2004../10348-sahih-muslim-book-004-hadith-number-1032.html) in Sahih Muslim that the Prophet (Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam) said: "A black dog is **devil**". Ibn Taimiya (May Allah's Mercy be upon him) said: 'The black dog is a **devil**, and the jinn often appear in its form, since the black color can bring the devilish powers more than other colors.

3) The jinn can appear in the shape of *snakes*. Thus, the Messenger (Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam) banned killing home snakes lest may any of them be a Muslim jinn. Abu Said al-Khudri (Radiya Allahu Anhu) said that Allah's Messenger (Sallallahu Alaihi wa Sallam) said: "There are Muslim Jinn in al-Madina: If one appears to you, in any form, you are to admonish it to depart for three days. If it appears after that, you must kill it, for it is truly a **devil**". [Reported by Imam Muslim]

Comment: Regarding point 3, does that suggest that the Jinn should not appear to us in any form!

Comment: Can you share the Hadith on the Black "Dog" & Black "Cat"?